# The RecyclerView doesn't load any data from Firebase and shows null for all the rows

Tags: firebase, kotlin, firebase-realtime-database, android-recyclerview

[enter image description here][1]

Although the code is formatted and implemented completely fine, there seems to a bug in the application that doesn't allow the app to retrieve and display the data. The complete components of back-end used for building the `RecyclerView`:

The fragment displaying the RecyclerView:

```
package com.reazon.foodrunner.fragment

import android.os.Bundle
import android.util.Log
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
import com.firebase.ui.database.FirebaseRecyclerAdapter
import com.google.firebase.database.*
import com.reazon.foodrunner.R
import com.reazon.foodrunner.adapter.HomeRecyclerAdapter
import com.reazon.foodrunner.model.Restaurants

class HomeFragment : Fragment() {

    private var mDatabaseReference: DatabaseReference? = null
    private var recyclerAdapter: HomeRecyclerAdapter? = null
    private var recyclerHome: RecyclerView? = null
    internal var restaurantsList: MutableList<Restaurants> = ArrayList()
    private var layoutManager: RecyclerView.LayoutManager? = null
    private lateinit var adapter: FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Restaurants,HomeRecyclerAdapter.HomeRecyclerViewHolder>
    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        val view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false)
        mDatabaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Restaurants")
        recyclerHome = view.findViewById(R.id.recyclerHomeAll)

        layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(activity)
        recyclerHome!!.layoutManager = layoutManager

        //retrieve data from firebase
        retrieveAllRestaurants()

        return view
    }

    private fun retrieveAllRestaurants() {
        restaurantsList.clear()
        val restaurantReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().reference.child("Restaurants")

        restaurantReference.addValueEventListener(object : ValueEventListener {
            override fun onCancelled(error: DatabaseError) {
                Log.d("ERROR ", "" + error.message)
            }

            override fun onDataChange(p0: DataSnapshot) {
                for (snapshot in p0.children) {
                    val restaurant = snapshot.getValue(Restaurants::class.java)
                    restaurant!!.getRestaurant()
                    restaurant.getRestaurantRating()
                    restaurant.getCostForOne()
                    restaurant.getRestaurantName()

                    restaurantsList.add(restaurant)

                }
                recyclerAdapter = HomeRecyclerAdapter(context!! , restaurantsList)
                recyclerHome?.adapter = recyclerAdapter
            }
        })
    }
}
```

The model class used:-

**Model Class**

```
package com.reazon.foodrunner.model

class Restaurants {
    private var id: String? = null
    private var name: String? = null
    private var rating: String? = null
    private var cost_for_one: String? = null
    private var imageUrl: String? = null

    constructor()

    constructor(
        id: String,
        name: String,
        rating: String,
        cost_for_one: String,
        imageUrl: String
    ) {
        this.id = id
        this.name = name
        this.rating = rating
        this.cost_for_one = cost_for_one
        this.imageUrl = imageUrl
    }

    fun getRestaurant(): String? {
        return imageUrl
    }

    fun setRestaurant(imageUrl: String){
        this.imageUrl = imageUrl
    }

    fun getRestaurantId(): String? {
        return id
    }

    fun setRestaurantId(id: String){
        this.id = id
    }

    fun getRestaurantName(): String? {
        return name
    }

    fun setRestaurantName(name: String){
        this.name = name
    }
    fun getRestaurantRating(): String? {
        return rating
    }
    fun setRestaurantRating(rating: String){
        this.rating = rating
    }

    fun getCostForOne(): String? {
        return cost_for_one
    }
    fun setCostForOne(cost_for_one: String) {
        this.cost_for_one = cost_for_one
    }
}
```

The Adapter Class used:-
**Adapter Class**

```
package com.reazon.foodrunner.adapter

import android.content.Context
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import android.widget.ImageButton
import android.widget.ImageView
import android.widget.TextView
import android.widget.Toast
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
import com.reazon.foodrunner.R
import com.reazon.foodrunner.model.Restaurants
import com.squareup.picasso.Picasso

class HomeRecyclerAdapter(
    var context: Context,
    var restaurantsList: List<Restaurants>
) : RecyclerView.Adapter<HomeRecyclerAdapter.HomeRecyclerViewHolder>() {

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): HomeRecyclerViewHolder {
        val view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context)
            .inflate(R.layout.recycler_home_single_row, parent, false)
        return HomeRecyclerViewHolder(view)
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return restaurantsList.size
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: HomeRecyclerViewHolder, position: Int) {
        val restaurant = restaurantsList[position]
        holder.costForOne.text = restaurant.getCostForOne().toString()
        holder.rating.text = restaurant.getRestaurantRating().toString()
        holder.textView.text = restaurant.getRestaurantName()
            Picasso.get().load(restaurant.getRestaurant()).placeholder(R.drawable.food_runner_icon).into(holder.imageView).toString() 
        holder.btnFavourite.setOnClickListener {
            Toast.makeText(context ,"Favourite Button Clicked",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
        }
    }

    class HomeRecyclerViewHolder(view: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(view) {
        var imageView: ImageView = view.findViewById(R.id.imgRestaurantImage)
        var costForOne: TextView = view.findViewById(R.id.txtCostForOne)
        var textView: TextView = view.findViewById(R.id.txtRestaurantName)
        var btnFavourite: ImageButton = view.findViewById(R.id.btnFavourite)
        var rating: TextView = view.findViewById(R.id.txtRating)
    }
}
```

Firebase database structure :
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/XDrxa.png

Comment: can you show the firebase database structure ?

Comment: yes , its a list inside the Parent "Restaurants"    https://i.stack.imgur.com/XDrxa.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Although the code is formatted and implemented completely fine, there seems to a bug in the application that doesn't allow the app to retrieve and display the data.

The main problem in your code lies in your `Restaurants` class, where the name of all your getters is incorrect. If you have in your class a property named `id`, the corresponding getter should be `getId()` and **not** `getRestaurantId()`. On the other hand, the setter should be `setId()` and **not** `setRestaurantId()`. There are two ways in which you can solve this problem. The first one would be to change all the names of all getters/setters according to the example above.

Also please note that the setters and the getters are not mandatory. Setters are always optional because if there is no setter for a JSON property, the Firebase client will set the value directly onto the field. However, a simpler way in which you can create such a class is define and initialize the properties directly into the constructor and set the class as a `data class`:

```
data class Restaurant(
    var id: String? = null,
    var name: String? = null,
    var rating: String? = null,
    var cost_for_one: String? = null,
    var imageUrl: String? = null
)
```

Please also note that the name of the class is `Restaurant` and **not** `Restaurants`, and this is because this class can be considered a blueprint for a single restaurant and not for more restaurants.

Comment: I really don't know how to thank you and didn't actually quite understand how changing the variables optimized the code, but the solution worked. Thanks a lot.